# How to abort fetching HTTP request using AbortController on the same button

Tags: javascript, api, http, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

The problem is that I need to get only last API response by clicking a "Fetch Data" button. Earlier requests should be canceled.

The idea is to use AbrotController. Unfortunately, I have a problem, because the requests are not canceled and a console receives the message:

> Fetch 1 error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The user aborted
> a request.

Sample code below:

```
<button id="test">Fetch data</button>

let isLoading = false;

let controller = new AbortController();
const abort = () => controller.abort();

const button = document.getElementById("test");

const fetchData = () => {
  controller = new AbortController();
  
  if (isLoading) {
    abort();
  }
  
  isLoading = true;
  
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
        signal: controller.signal
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.warn(`Fetch 1 error: ${e.message}`);
      })
      .finally(() => isLoading = false);;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetchData();
});
```

Comment: Another approach could be to use RXjs's Observables, which make it easy to get only the last fetched value and discard the previous ones (that's standard in Angular), as well as debounce, distinctUntilChanged, and many other things. Also `await fetch(...);` is way easier to write, read, and manage than `.then()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you call the controller.abort() on different instance than you initialized signal.

What about something like this?

```
let isLoading = false;
let controller = new AbortController();

const abort = () => controller.abort();

const button = document.getElementById("test");

const fetchData = () => {
  if (isLoading) {
    abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
  }
  
  isLoading = true;
  
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
        signal: controller.signal
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.warn(`Fetch 1 error: ${e.message}`);
      })
      .finally(() => isLoading = false);
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetchData();
});
```